# Is it possible to restrict force merges to single ElasticSearch nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

The API for forcemerge restricts per index. I’d like to restrict further to only the segment size on a single node.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason you'd want to do this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Few different reasons:
(1) Forcemerge(s) cannot be cancelled. Isolating to a single node allows for more control in case of failure/retry.
(2) Prioritising based on load/resource usage. E.g. in cases of asymmetric distribution of disk usage across the cluster, you'd want to kick off forcemerge in order of disk usage %.